# Creating a simple application launcher with Eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, swing, deployment

I am very new to programming and need help or a cheat. I am trying to create an application for windows, using eclipse, that simply launches other applications from a drop down menu on the top toolbar. Kind of like how Hirens boot cd menu looks and works but with my own applications. They need to be ran off of a portable USB as well. Thanks in advance.

This is what I have so far.

```
import java.awt.EventQueue;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JMenuBar;
import javax.swing.JMenu;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.io.IOException;

public class Launcher {

    private JFrame frame;

    /**
     * Launch the application.
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                try {
                    Launcher window = new Launcher();
                    window.frame.setVisible(true);
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        });
    }

    /**
     * Create the application.
     */
    public Launcher() {
        initialize();
    }

    /**
     * Initialize the contents of the frame.
     */
    private void initialize() {
        frame = new JFrame();
        frame.setBounds(100, 100, 450, 300);
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

        JMenuBar menuBar = new JMenuBar();
        frame.setJMenuBar(menuBar);

        JMenu mnVirusRemoval = new JMenu("Virus Removal");
        menuBar.add(mnVirusRemoval);

        JButton btnFirefox = new JButton("Opera");
        btnFirefox.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {
                @SuppressWarnings("unused")
                Process process = null;

                try {
                    process = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("IDK WHAT GOES HERE");
                } 

                catch (IOException e) 

                {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        });
        mnVirusRemoval.add(btnFirefox);
    }

}
```

Comment: The best way to deploy a Java desktop application is using [Java Web Start](http://stackoverflow.com/tags/java-web-start/info).

Comment: 1) `process = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("IDK WHAT GOES HERE");`  That should go well.  See also [When Runtime.exec() won't](http://www.javaworld.com/article/2071275/core-java/when-runtime-exec---won-t.html) for many good tips on creating and handling a process correctly.  Then ignore it refers to `exec` and use a `ProcessBuilder` to create the process.  2) Please use code formatting for code and code snippets, structured documents like HTML/XML or input/output.  To do that, select the text and click the `{}` button at the top of the message posting editing form.

Comment: 3) `new JMenu("Virus Removal");` This is not software I'd write in Java.  It is too OS specific.

Comment: Take a look at `ProcessBuilder`

Comment: You will need to know where the programs are stored in order to be able to call them.  If the Java app is been run from the same USB, you could establish a relative context

Comment: `JButton btnFirefox = new JButton("Opera");` Accident or just trolling people? (just kidding :) Seriously speaking, I agree with `ProcessBuilder`. Also [Desktop](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/desktop.html) API could be used to launch an application but I'd go with the previous one.

Comment: cool thanks guys thats all i needed. im creating a windows program to access a toolbox for my computer repair company. (lol not trolling i used firefox and opera just to play with it sorry again if my coding is confusing)thanks again for the quick and professional response!